# D adding functionality to classes in an uncoupled way

Tags: inheritance, d, hierarchy

I wrote a class called Container which handles hierarchies (as visible to the class user) and converts them internally to a flat array. So for the outside of Container it looks like a hierarchy of Containers, each with parent and child nodes.

This functionality I want to add to certain classes. For example the Widget class, it must have that same functionality defined by Container.

I could let Widget inherit from Container. Container is now defined as a class with this(), data member, member functions, invariant and unittests. Container contains an array of Containers, so there is one fault in the design: what if Foobar also inherits Container and we add Foobar items to the Widget's container? That must be forbidden. They do share the same base class, but they are fundamentally different things with different purposes...they just seem to share some functionality.

Defining Container as an interface is not possible, since it contains data members (and doesn't solve the problem). Defining Container as mixin neither, since we have this() functionality too (or how would this work out?). Visibility attributes for functions in mixins doesn't work either. And additionally, I can't pass it the `this` argument of the Widget class, for that needs to be the first element of the flat array.

I thought of giving Container a template argument, telling it what container it is of:

```
abstract class Container(T)
{
    ...

    T[] elements;
}

class Widget: Container!Widget
{
}
```

This gives an error: class container.__unittest2.Widget base class is forward referenced by Container.

How would you implement this? I could also add checks in Container that makes sure that when a child is added, it has the same type as the parent. But how do I check that?

```
abstract class Container
{
    void add(Container child)
    {
        // pseudo-code
        assert (is(getFirstDerivedType(this) == getFirstDerivedType(child))); 

        ...
    }

    ...

    Container[] elements;
}
```

---

**EDIT:**
Even if the first piece of code does not signal an error, it still doesn't really solve the problem. I cannot arbitrarily add more functionality since only one base class is allowed. The others need to be interfaces, which are fundamentally different things. Interfaces ensure there is certain functionality in the derived class, they don't add the functionality themselves.

This is supposed to be solved with (template) mixins. But mixins cannot add code to the constructor (only replace if not defined), cannot add code to invariant (invariant multiple times defined), cannot specify member function visibility or use other class/struct specific keywords...

Comment: I'm not getting `error: class container.__unittest2.Widget base...`.  Care to share more?

Comment: This is strange. I cannot reproduce this in a simpler environment either. I suppose this is a compiler bug, because if I place the Widget definition inside the unittest, it signals an error. Otherwise it doesn't...but now I get "Assertion failure: 'global.errors' on line 4893 in file 'template.c' ; abnormal program termination" instead...

Comment: Could you use multiple sub-typing: add `Container` as a sub-type of `Widget`? (I'm not an expert: I just read about this technique in the D book a few days ago and it seems relevant to your problem.)

Comment: @Xophmeister: Precisely. Container should be a Widget too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are going about this the wrong way. You are trying to add functionality to a variety of classes from the inside, whereas it would make much more sense to add it from the outside, i.e. extend them.

The Container should contain the Widget, not the other way around. You can then use `alias this` to forward non-container calls to the contained Widget.

Something like this:

```
import std.stdio;

class Container(T)
{
public:
    this(T elem) { m_this = elem; add(this); }
    void add(Container elem) { m_elems ~= elem; }

    alias m_this this;

private:
    T m_this;
    Container m_elems[];
}

class Widget
{
public:
    this(int x) { this.m_x = x; }
    int foo() { return m_x; }
    int m_x;
}

alias Container!Widget CWidget;

void main()
{
    CWidget w1 = new CWidget(new Widget(1));
    CWidget w2 = new CWidget(new Widget(2));

    w1.add(w2);
    writeln(w1.m_x);
    writeln(w1.foo());
}
```

Notice how you can still use `w1` like a `Widget` by calling `w1.m_x` and `w1.foo()`.

Comment: Isn't a mixin supposed to be used for code-reusal and not inheritance?

Comment: Lots of things can be used for code-reuse. Mixins are one, inheritance is another. However, I have just noticed your edit, I will have a think about this because I don't think my answer is satisfactory.

Comment: Have you thought of something?

Comment: This way you can add an arbitrary number of functionality classes, nice!

Answer (score 2):

**Update**: I'm not sure what your examples have to do with the question. D does not allow you to add functionality to a class outside of modifying the class.

Inheritance doesn't let you extend functionality of the base class, only modify it.

Mixins only let you "mix in" pre-defined functionality. Again, you can't modify an existing class with it.

One option you haven't looked at is "alias this." This creates a composition relationship, which again, does not allow modifying the existing class or even the one containing it.

---

```
import std.stdio;

struct B
{
   int p, q, r, s;
}

struct A
{
    B b;
    alias b this;

    void foo() {
        p = 6;
    }
}

void main()
{
    A a;
    a.foo();

    writeln(a.p);
}
```

---

Or maybe what we need is to do some code generation and use string mixins.

And the last option is change your design. Instead of creating a mixin that modifies invariants/constructors and the likes, create a mixin that provides functions which can be called by the implementer of the class. "Mixin the MyContainer template and then call TestMe in your invariant."

**Comments on statements**:

> there is one fault in the design: what if Foobar also inherits Container and we add Foobar items to the Widget's container? That must be forbidden.

Then don't put an array of Containers in Container.

```
class Widget {
    Widget[] elements;
}
```

Note that in your the example using templates, even if you it was working (and it should), Container!(Widget) is not the same class as Container!(SomeClass). So effectively to solve your problem:

```
class ContainerWidget {
    Widget[] elements;
}

class ContainerSomeClass {
    SomeClass[] elements;
}
```

To properly support a flat array you would have to create a tagged Container similar to how a tagged union would work.

Comment: What I wanted was composition. But instead the function of the composited data member would be in the class scope, not in the data member's scope. There are a few ugly ways to do this. To me it feels like mixins are too simplistic currently. It nicely can add normal functions etc, but within classes/structs it has restricted use (IMO).

Comment: @Daevius, you may want to look at the example I added for alias this. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: That is indeed a neat way for a single composited data member to be represented at class scope. But it's limited in that you can only add the functionality of one class this way. Multiple `alias this` are not allowed, so you can only add the functionality of one class to another. Not an arbitrary number...

Comment: @Daevius, that is only a limitation of the compiler implementation, the language does allow for multiple alias this inside a class.

Comment: Thank you for the information, he_the_great! I hope it gets added sometime soon ;)

Comment: Well, http://www.d-programming-language.org/class.html says: "There is only one AliasThis allowed per class or struct."

Comment: @Daevius, that should be updated too. http://d.puremagic.com/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=6083

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I would make Container be a Widget. That is how it is done in many existing GUI toolkits anyway, and it does make sense to be so.

Comment: Yes that is a nice idea. I just thought like this: many widgets contain other widgets (scrollbar consists of 3 buttons for example). But maybe it makes more sense to handle this internally and not through a more general hierarchy. The problem still remains for (other) generic cases though.

Comment: There are also many benefits of doing so as well. In FLTK for an example, the `fltk::Group` is also a `fltk::Widget`. In Java SWING, JComponent is actually holding a list of JComponents...